# Set permanent command shortcut in terminal to cd to Downloads

Tags: command-line, bash, permissions, alias

I wrote a new text file in `/bin` named `ram` which contains:

```
watch -n 1 free -h
```

and a file `sen`:

```
watch -n 1 sensors
```

in the same folder, in order to avoid typing

```
watch blahblahblah...
```

every time.

Also, I changed permissions of these two from

```
-rw-r--r--
```

to

```
-rw-r--r-x
```

and achieved my goal. It worked even after reopening shell, i.e. then I could type `ram` instead of `watch -n 1 free -h`

But, problem was encountered after I tried the same procedure for

```
cd /home/myname/Downloads/
```

and new text file saved in `/bin` and named `dow`, same with permissions.

This time `dow` does nothing in terminal, even not showing any message.

I tried saving the same file in `/usr/bin`, but again terminal does nothing and my working directory doesn't change.

How is this possible?

Comment: Related: [Why doesn't "cd" work in a shell script?](//askubuntu.com/q/481715)

Answer (score 7):

You have written a script, and it works. It just doesn't do what you want, because a script runs in a separate shell from the shell that calls it.

The shell that the script runs in does exactly what the script tells it to; it changes its working directory to `~/Downloads`. There is nothing else for it to do, so it exits. The calling shell's directory hasn't been changed.

You don't have to take my word for it - you can demonstrate it by adding `ls` on the next line of your `dow` file. The contents of your `~/Downloads` directory (assuming it has some) will then be listed when you run the command (without the usual colours, which are provided by an alias in your `~/.bashrc` that non-interactive shells don't read).

To execute a script in the current shell, you can use the `source` command, which can also be written as `. file`. So, if you type

```
. dow
```

Your current shell will change directory.

Or, you can instead set an alias:

```
zanna@toaster:~$ alias dow='cd $HOME/Downloads'
zanna@toaster:~$ dow
zanna@toaster:~/Downloads$
```

To make it permanent, add the line

```
alias dow='cd $HOME/Downloads'
```

to your `~/.bashrc` file. It will then be available every time you run an interactive shell.

Comment: Worth adding that an `alias` is probably a better approach for for the `watch` commands too.

Comment: @BoristheSpider agreed, but could you give a solid justification? I was tempted to add "and why are you putting your own programs here instead of `~/bin` or `/usr/local/bin`?", but I don't have any justification besides convention and PATH precedence...

Comment: Convention is a powerful reason. Further, allowing unpriviledged users of the system to dump random executables into `/bin` is rather ... dangerous. `~/bin` would be a better choice, in which case how a user handles _their_ environment is their own choice.

Answer (score 3):

This is a cross-site duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/a/255415/383694.

The issue is that the script is run in a subshell. The script changes directory and then closes, making no change to your current shell.

Two mitigations:

1. execute `. dow` to make the script run in the context of the current shell.
2. use an alias, eg in your ~/.bashrc file that does the directory change - eg `alias dow="cd /home/myname/Downloads/"`.

If you're changing directory it's usually a good idea to test that it worked before doing other things.

There are some other options in the linked question.